# How to send half filled form data to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a long form that user needs to fill, it has 10 multiple choice questions. We are facing an issue that users are filling 4-5 questions and then stop filling it further.

We want to send this partially filled form information to the server.

One way to do this is by sending the data at each step i.e. as soon as user answers any question. But this would result in too many API hits and slow down the filling process at the client end.

Is there any other way to achieve this i.e. by using js unload event or can we detect on the client side when user is changing-tab/closing-browser/ or using any other methods to exit our page?

Comment: How is your form currently implemented? Multi page or sinle page? Do you have code snippets for the form?

Comment: Maybe you could use `setTimeout()` to send the changes some time after the user starts filling in the form.

Comment: SO is not really an appropriate site for brainstorming designs. You need to decide what you want to do, then try to code it. If you can't get it working as desired, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar: But setTimeout() would not fire if user closes the tab or browser

Comment: @maverick You could use it in combination with an `onunload` handler. So if they go idle it will save their changes, and also when they close the window.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp this isn't working

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time for forms to capture potential form abandonments.  So every time there's a blur on an input field, it checks frequency and sends the form data as a post to a handler where you can receive the data and do what you need at that /abandoned/handler.php file.

Javascript (be sure JQuery is initialized first):

```
function sendAbandoned() {
        var now = new Date();
        now = Math.floor(now / 1000);

        if ((now - lastUpdate) < 10) {
            // make sure doesn't send too many "updates"
            return false;
        }


        lastUpdate = now;
        var formArr=$("form[name='formName']").serializeArray();

        $.post('/path/to/abandoned/handler.php',
        formArr);
    }


    $("form[name='formName'] input").blur(function () {
        sendAbandoned();
    });
```

Comment: this is not working.. i tried using this link (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_name). Since, w3schools do not allow to modify the code & share it, you can find the modified code (https://jsfiddle.net/twczwzkc/)

Comment: Well, this answers the question and it works, so I got a down vote with no explanation?  Likely because I failed to state JQuery must be initialized for the script, though that's pretty obvious from the $?  Stack member mantra:  "Let no good deed go unpunished" LOL

Comment: Thanks for the update.. may be my bad but its not working even with jquery.. try this code https://jsfiddle.net/twczwzkc/1/ on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_name link

Comment: any update, can you check this and suggest if I'm doing something wrong here?